# Set up VPN with Verizon FiOS

Tags: vpn, fios

I am trying to set it up so that I can access my home network via a VPN connection, but I am getting the following error:

#### Error Message

`Error 809: The network connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be established because the remote server is not responding.  This could be because one of the network devices (e.g. firewalls, NAT, routers, etc.) between your computer and the remote server is not configured to allow VPN connections.  Please contact your Administrator or your service provider to determine which device may be causing the problem.`

Here is my current setup:

#### VPN Server

Synology DS1511+ using the VPN Server package.
Protocol: PPTP VPN
Internal IP: 192.168.1.3
Dynamic Address: 10.0.0.0
Authentication: MS-CHAP v2
Encryption: Require MPPE (40/128 bit)
MTU: 1400
Use manual DNS (which is pointing to my network's domain server).

I also have the firewall of the NAS allowing traffic from TCP 1723.

#### Router

Verizon FiOS with a dynamic IP address (DynDNS).
Model: MI424WR (Rev 2)
The router does not hand  le DHCP or DNS (DHCP is handled by NAS and DNS is handled by domain server).
I have forwarded ports 1723 and 1701 to the NAS.

I cannot find a setting for 'VPN passthrough' in the router's configuration.

I have tried setting up the NAS to be linked as a DMZ, but it didn't seem to change anything.

I'm out of ideas - help!